# Doing a division of two aggregate queries in SQL with where condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tried searching for a solution couldn't find it.

I need to compare the number of defects on a car by model and only a certain type of defect, and compare that with the total numbers of cars by model to get a percent of defects such as

```
select car,count(distinct model) 
where defect_code=123 
group by car

select car,count(distinct model) group by car
```

How would I write this query? An optimized way would be preferred.

Comment: please provide sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Join

```
SELECT car,
       Df_cnt / T_cnt
FROM   (SELECT car,
               Count(DISTINCT model) Df_cnt From tablename
        WHERE  defect_code = 123
        GROUP  BY car) A
       JOIN (SELECT car,
                    Count(DISTINCT model) T_cnt from tablename
             GROUP  BY car) b
         ON A.car = b.car
```

Comment: Error: The sub query is returning more than one value.

Comment: @user3512885 - My bad didn't check the `Group By`. Try the new answer

Comment: Column 'B.cnt' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @user3512885 - check now

Comment: where are the table names?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP
FROM
(
SELECT 'MARUTI' CAR,'SWIFT' MODEL,123 DEFECT_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'MARUTI' CAR,'ALTO' MODEL,123 DEFECT_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'HYUNDAI' CAR,'ACCENT' MODEL,123 DEFECT_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NISSAN' CAR,'DATSON' MODEL,123 DEFECT_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'HONDA' CAR,'CITY' MODEL,123 DEFECT_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'HYUNDAI' CAR,'ACCENT' MODEL,115 DEFECT_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NISSAN' CAR,'DATSON' MODEL,117 DEFECT_CODE
UNION ALL
SELECT 'HONDA' CAR,'CITY' MODEL,118 DEFECT_CODE
)TAB
```

Query to find count of defective cars of a CAR

```
SELECT  DISTINCT CAR,DEFECT_CODE,COUNT(MODEL) OVER(PARTITION BY CAR) CARCOUNT 
FROM #TEMP
WHERE DEFECT_CODE=123
```

Result

[image]

Query to find count of defective cars of a CAR's model

```
SELECT *,COUNT(MODEL) OVER(PARTITION BY CAR,MODEL) CARMODELCOUNT 
FROM #TEMP
WHERE DEFECT_CODE=123
```

Result

[image]